# How to use Guice or Spring to inject a list of objects based on properties

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, guice

I have a class like the one below.

```
public class Person {

    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

My intention is to inject a `List<Person>` into another class where the list should be created from a property file. 
Something like this.

```
persons(0)=John
persons(1)=Jake
```

Comment: Java configuration. Annotations.

Comment: Very specific requirement. Looks like you had to write a lot of custom code. Did you?

Answer (score -1):

Here you have Spring example. 
Try like that, you can add as many properties as you want. Or just iterate over properties.In properties file just set the property `person=Name`. If the properties file is in the project resources file then Spring will find it automatically.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyProperties {

    @Value("${person}")
    private String person;

    public String getPerson(){
    return this.person;
    } 

}

public class anotherClass {

@Atowired
MyProperties myProperties;

List<Person> createObjectsBasingOnProperties(){
   ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
   persons.add(new Person(myProperties.getPerson()));
   return persons;  

}

}
```